# Best way to sort triangles in a 3d engine?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, graphics, 3d

I'm coding a 3d engine in Java and I keep getting a reoccurring but where when sorting my triangles at certain angles some triangles are rendered in the wrong order. I'm sorting the triangles by averaging out the x, y, and z points of the triangle and measuring the distance from the camera. Is there a better method for sorting triangles in a 3d engine with a camera.

My Code (Java):

```
    Collections.sort(tris, new Comparator<triangle>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(triangle t1, triangle t2) {
            //boolean s = ((((t1.p[0].z + t1.p[1].z + t1.p[2].z + t1.z) / 3.0f) - cam.z)) > (((t2.p[0].z + t2.p[1].z + t2.p[2].z + t1.z) / 3.0f));
            
            vec3d v1 = new vec3d(((t1.p[0].x + t1.p[1].x + t1.p[2].x + t1.x) / 3.0f),((t1.p[0].y + t1.p[1].y + t1.p[2].y + t1.y) / 3.0f),((t1.p[0].z + t1.p[1].z + t1.p[2].z + t1.z) / 3.0f));
            vec3d v2 = new vec3d(((t2.p[0].x + t2.p[1].x + t2.p[2].x + t2.x) / 3.0f),((t2.p[0].y + t2.p[1].y + t2.p[2].y + t2.y) / 3.0f),((t2.p[0].z + t2.p[1].z + t2.p[2].z + t2.z) / 3.0f));

            double val1 = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(v1.x - cam.x)*Math.abs(v1.x - cam.x)+Math.abs(v1.y - cam.y)*Math.abs(v1.y - cam.y)+Math.abs(v1.z - cam.z)*Math.abs(v1.z - cam.z));
            double val2 = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(v2.x - cam.x)*Math.abs(v2.x - cam.x)+Math.abs(v2.y - cam.y)*Math.abs(v2.y - cam.y)+Math.abs(v2.z - cam.z)*Math.abs(v2.z - cam.z));
                    
            boolean s = val1 < val2;
            
            
            return s ? 1 : -1;
        }
    });
```

Comment: There's no point in using `Math.abs` on a number you're about to square anyway.  There's also no point in using `Math.sqrt`, if all you're using this calculation for is ordering.  One concern I have is that if two triangles are equidistant from the camera, your comparator returns -1, where it should return 0.  I'm not sure that would put triangles in the wrong order though.  Have you got an example of two triangles that end up in the wrong order?

Comment: Just because the center of triangle A is farther from the camera than the center of triangle B doesn't mean that A is behind B.

Comment: In fact, I don't think it's possible to sort triangles. Cycles like A in front of B, B in front of C, and C in front of A are not sortable.

Comment: with sorting you have to cut all the intersecting triangles into subtriangles and sort that ... its much faster and easier to implement depth buffer instead of depth sorting unless you really need to sort for some reason (like transparency)